# How scroll in sidebar keyboard Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublimetext4

Is it possible to scroll in sidebar with keyboard. When you have large number of files when you get to the bottom scroll stops at last file and you can’t see files below. You can put mouse over sidebar and scroll that way but is it possible to scroll with keyboard?

Comment: I found out btw today, that on Windows you can swap two lines by pressing `CTRL + Shift + up/down`.  That said, for me it works to scroll with keyboard **sometimes**. On Windows.

Comment: Most of the times it does not xD

Comment: Just today I filed a..."bug". https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/pair-of-brackets-after-around-150-lines/71360/2 

Answer (score 0):

Do CTRL+0 (zero) and this will focus your cursor on the Side Bar, once there You can use your arrows to go down and up. **I see the list of files is working correctly despite You have so many files that the list is higher than the focusable area from the sidebar.**

To hide/show the sidebar with the CTRL+K & CTRL+B , this same combination applies for show/view depending on the state of the sidebar. You can see on the View -> Side Bar -> Show Side Bar CTRL+K, CTRK+B. This works by pressing the CTRL and then the K (press and then release) and then the B (same thing, press and then release).

Then what You can do is CTRL+TAB OR CTRL+TAB+SHIFT. The first one will iterate the files on the sidebar in the forward direction (down), and the second combination (including SHIFT) will iterate the opened files in the backward direction (up).

I'm using this version because have in mind that depending on the version You can find differences. You did not specify any version but this is the one I'm using:

[image]